# Number fields – dual basis of an additive set (Marcus Chapter 3 Exercise 34b)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am working through the exercises in Marcus's Number Fields textbook and am not sure how to proceed on Chapter 3, Exercise 34(b).

Given $K, L$ number fields, $R$ the ring of integers of $K$, and $A$ an additive subgroup of $L$, the exercises define $A^* = \{ \alpha \in L\ |\ \text{Tr}^{L}_{K}(\alpha A) \subset R \}$.

In part (a) I've proved that for any basis $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$ of $L$ over $K$ there is a dual basis of $L$ over $K$ $\{\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n\}$ such that $\text{Tr}^{L}_{K}(\alpha_i \beta_j)$ is 1 if $i = j$, 0 otherwise.

Part (b) asks us to show that if $A = R\alpha_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus R \alpha_n$ that $A^{*} = B$ where $B$ is the $R$-module generated by the $\beta_i$.

The suggested approach is to take $\gamma \in A^{*}$, show there exists $\beta$ such that $\text{Tr}^{K}_{L}((\gamma -  \beta)A) = 0$, and that this implies $\gamma = \beta$.

Here's my approach so far:

- Let $\gamma \in A^{*}$ and define $m_i = \text{Tr}^{K}_{L}(\gamma\alpha_i)$; by assumption $m_i \in R$.  Take $\beta = \sum_{i=1}^{n} m_i \beta_i$
- For $\alpha \in A$, $\alpha = r_1 \alpha_1 \oplus r_n \alpha_n$ and $\text{Tr}^{L}_{K}(\gamma\alpha) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} r_i m_i = \text{Tr}^{L}_{K}(\beta\alpha)$.
- Therefore $\text{Tr}^{K}_{L}((\gamma - \beta)A) = 0$.

Where I'm stuck is the last step - showing this implies $\gamma = \beta$.

It's possible for an non-zero additive set to have a zero trace (in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}]$ the set $\{\sqrt{n}, 2\sqrt{n}, \ldots\}$ has zero trace), so I'm guessing it must follow from the fact that the $\beta_i$s are a basis for $L$?

Thanks for any assistance you can give.

Comment: I think you are almost done. Note that $A$ contains a basis of $L$ over $K$, and that the trace induces a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $L$ with values in $K$, namely $(x,y)$ goes to $Tr(xy)$. Please check the details.

Comment: I'll work through those and post an update.  Much appreciated.

Comment: well, you are done, by part a). I just read your post again. Indeed, $\gamma-\beta$ is an element of $L$, so it can be written as a linear combination of the $\beta_i$ with coefficients in $K$. Then consider $Tr((\gamma-\beta)\alpha_j)$. This must be $0$ for any $j$ by the last thing you proved. This implies that the $\beta_j$ coefficient of $\gamma-\beta$ vanishes for all $j$. Hence $\gamma-\beta = 0$.

Comment: Another way I was looking at this after your previous comment was that since $\gamma - \beta \in L$, if the quantity is non-zero then $(\gamma - \beta)^{-1} \in L$.  So it can be written as a product of the $\alpha_i$ with coefficients in $K$.  Since $K$ is a field of fractions of $R$ there is then some $r \neq 0$ that clears the denominators so that $r(\gamma - \beta)^{-1} \in A$.  The trace of the product of this element with $\gamma - \beta$ should be $r \cdot Tr(1) = r[L : K] \neq 0$ but by what's proved above the trace is 0.  Therefore $\gamma - \beta = 0$.

Comment: Interesting comment. Yes, that works too :).

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I had missed in the transition from part (a) to part (b) that $A$ was no longer just a general additive set but a free $R$ module on the basis elements.  Really appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is a free $R$-module generated by the $\alpha_i$, each $\alpha_i \in A$.  If $(\gamma - \beta)^{-1} \neq 0 \in L$, it can be written as a sum of the $\alpha_i$ with coefficients in $K$.  As $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$ there is some $r \neq 0$ such that $r$ clears the denominators of the coefficients of the $\alpha_i$ and so $r(\gamma - \beta)^{-1} \in A$.  Then $\text{Tr}^{L}_{K}(r(\gamma - \beta)(\gamma - \beta)^{-1}) = \text{Tr}^{L}_{K}(r) = rn$ where $n = [L : K]$.  However $\text{Tr}^{L}_{K}((\gamma - \beta)\alpha) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in A$.  Therefore $\gamma - \beta = 0$.